# Calling a java-script function when value of a Dojo auto-completer changes

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dojo, struts2

I am trying to call a javascript function when the value of a Dojo auto completer changes.

Calling the javascript function from the "onChange" attribute has no effect (I mean the function is not called/executed).

In the javascript function I want to:

1. Call a struts2 action.
2. Change the value of a hidden field.

For calling the action I have another way :
publishing a topic using attribute " valueNotifyTopic="topicName" ", then I can call an action by listening to the topic.

But I cant change the value of the hidden field through this way. So I need to call a javascript function

Please advise

Thanks!!

Edit:

This is the code in the jsp:

```
<s:url id="scriptURL" action="viewContactInfo" />
<sd:div href="%{scriptURL}" listenTopics="viewContactInfo" formId="contactInfo" showLoadingText="false" preload="false">
<s:form id="contactInfo">
    <sd:autocompleter autoComplete="false" name="customer" list="customerList" valueNotifyTopics="viewContactInfo"/> 
    <sd:autocompleter autoComplete="false" name="contact"  list="contactList"  valueNotifyTopics="viewContactInfo"/>
    <s:hidden id="chngd" value="initial"/>
</s:form>
</sd:div>
```

Here if I change "valueNotifyTopics='viewContactInfo'" to "onChange='dojo.event.topic.publish('viewContactInfo');'" the action "viewContactInfo" stops getting called. Whereas the same thing (the "onChange" one) works with other elements (in other places in my project).

Comment: As a thought, I think this might be happening because dojo autocompleter is not a html element and the onChange event handler works only on html elements. what do you think ?

Comment: Using a topic is the correct approach, as to why it's not working, difficult to say with what's given--you *can* change a hidden value via a topic method.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to create the dojo widget you are having problems with.

Comment: @BuffaloBuffalo The code is wrapped in the S2 custom tag, it's more likely the topic "subscription" or handler itself is incorrect.

Comment: Please see the edit for the code and further description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had started another thread for this question.

I figured out the solution and have posted the answer here :

[Cannot find a way to pass a hidden value to the action file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7750679/870767)

Hope this helps!!