# Cannot find a way to pass a hidden value to the action file

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dojo, struts2

**Situation:**

I have two dojo autocompleters on a jsp. Both of them trigger the same action when their value is changed. Now I want that in the action file I should know which autocompleter was changed.

**What I have done:**

Normally, in such a situation I would call a javascript to change the value of a hidden field and then access the value of that hidden field in the action file to know which was changed. But I call the javascript using the "onChange" attribute which (unfortunately) does not work for "autocompleter". I had to use "valueNotifyTopics" for calling the action.

Here is the code:

```
<s:url id="scriptURL" action="viewContactInfo" />
<sd:div href="%{scriptURL}" listenTopics="viewContactInfo" formId="contactInfo" showLoadingText="false" preload="false">
<s:form id="contactInfo">
    <sd:autocompleter autoComplete="false" name="customer" list="customerList" valueNotifyTopics="viewContactInfo"/> 
    <sd:autocompleter autoComplete="false" name="contact"  list="contactList" valueNotifyTopics="viewContactInfo"/>
    <s:hidden id="chngd" value="initial"/>
</s:form>
</sd:div>
```

I was hoping to use something like this:

```
onchange="dojo.byId('chngd').value='some value'; dojo.event.topic.publish('viewContactInfo');"
```

instead of

```
valueNotifyTopics="viewContactInfo"
```

Please advise some way of getting around the situation I have mentioned.

Thanks!!

In case I missed out any required information please leave a comment.

Comment: I don't understand; I thought we [went through this already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565149/calling-a-java-script-function-when-value-of-a-dojo-auto-completer-changes). Why can't you change the hidden value in the topic handler code? In any case, the answer is correct, the hidden field needs a name, and a setter in the action.

Comment: Hi Dave, my problem did not get solved there and the thread went dead, so had to start a new thread. And adding a name attribute may have helped if I had not been able to access the value of the hidden field in the action. But the problem is that I can not change the value of the hidden field. Anyways I added the attribute and checked, just in case but nothing happened.

Comment: Of course you can access the hidden field, what makes you believe you can't?

Comment: (Sorry was just editing my comments so deleted them temporarily). For topic handler I am using the div tag for calling an action. Now how would I change the value of hidden field in div according to the element which triggered the topic.

Comment: Basically I need something which does exactly what this code is doing in the autocompleter tag, because here onChange is not doing its job ---> onchange="dojo.byId('chngd').value='some value'; dojo.event.topic.publish('viewContactInfo');" <---

Comment: And I'm saying put the value change in the topic handler.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is the topic handler here, but I guess for topic handler I am using the "div" tag (for calling an action). Now how should I change the value of hidden field in "div" according to the element which triggered the topic.

Comment: Oh, I see; there's no explicit topic handler, just a listen topic on the div to do the update. Since you need to perform additional actions, like I said in the other thread, I'd probably create a topic handler; from there you can publish the topic for the div. There may be a way to hook in to the implicit topic handler, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: I will look up for topic handler right away. But do you have any ideas as to why onChange is not working?

Comment: Because a Dojo component is not a straight HTML component, it's a Dojo widget.

Comment: Hmmm.... I had guessed it would be so because I found, there is nothing for onChange in the library files for dojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured this out a while back, but am posting this answer now, for anyone still in trouble:

In the jsp do this:

```
<sd:autocompleter autoComplete="false" name="customer" list="customerList" valueNotifyTopics="topic"/>
```

Then in javascript do this:

```
dojo.event.topic.subscribe("topic", function(){
    dojo.byId('chngd').value='some value';
    dojo.event.topic.publish('getLists');
});
```

This way, when the value of a dojo autocompleter is changed, you can set the value of a hidden field before your action is called. For that matter you can do a whole lot more, because this is like, you are doing this --> `onclick="topic()"` .

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the name-attribute for #chngd (only fields with a name-attribute will be submitted)

Comment: Hi Dr.Molle,
Thanks for a quick reply.
The problem here is that the action is not getting called when I use onChange attribute. If the action gets called, I will be able to access the value. I have used this method in other places where a drop down or a text box is used.

Comment: If there is some way through which I can call a javascript from the autocompleter, that will do the job (I hope! Because the javascript should be executed before the topic is notified).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with struts, but the name-attribute is required anyway if you want to submit the field.

Comment: Hi Dr.Molle, I tried adding the name attribute as well but it did not help. Thanks anyways.